# A stored procedure to convert given CSV string to rows. E.g. Input String: 'a,b,c,d’

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008-r2

Required output

```
String
abc
bbbc
cdd
```

I have tried this but wont work.

```
create procedure CSVtoROWS(in 'str' varchar(50))

begin 
declare i int;
declare j int;
declare temp_str varchar(50);
/*find number of words in given string which is equal to rows*/ 

set i= length(str)-length(replace(str,',',''))+1;

set j=1;

drop table if exists #tabQ1
create table #tabQ1
    (
     String varchar(50) null default null
    );
while(j<=i) do
set temp_str=LEFT(str,charIndex(',',str)-1,len(str))
set str= SUBSTRING(str,(CHARINDEX(',', @StringInput),
                             LEN(@StringInput)) + 1, LEN(@StringInput))
insert into tabQ1
values(temp_str);
setj=j+1;
End while;
select * from TableforQ1;   
END
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this

```
CREATE PROCEDURE CSVtoROWS
(
  @S VARCHAR(100)
) -- CSVtoROWS 'String,abc,bbbc,cdd'
AS 
BEGIN

 SELECT Split.a.value('.', 'VARCHAR(100)') AS String  
 FROM  (SELECT CAST ('<M>' + REPLACE(@S, ',', '</M><M>') + '</M>' AS XML) AS String ) AS A 
 CROSS APPLY String.nodes ('/M') AS Split(a);

END
```

and also check the below link for reference

http://www.sqljason.com/2010/05/converting-single-comma-separated-row.html

Answer (score 0):

You could try something like this:

```
create procedure CSVtoROWS
  @S varchar(50)
as

declare @T table(string varchar(50))

while len(@S) > 0
begin
  insert into @T values(left(@S, charindex(',', @S+',')-1))
  set @S = stuff(@S, 1, charindex(',', @S+','), '')
end

select string from @T
```

Or you could use a string split function of your choice.
[Split strings the right way – or the next best way](http://www.sqlperformance.com/2012/07/t-sql-queries/split-strings)